# Odata $expand collection of a null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, odata

I have a strange bug with odata `$expand`. If I expand the collection of a null object I am getting an error

> "Value cannot be null"

This is my query :

```
GET  localhost/OData/Location(10)/?$expand=position($expand=area($expand=points))
```

This query generates the error

> "Value cannot be null"

Shouldn't expand stop to the first null object ?
Here area is null.

My classes are like that :

```
Location 
    - Position 
        - Area 
            - Anchor
            - ICollection<Points>

Location
{
    public Position position { get; set; }
}

Position
{
    public Area area { get; set; }
}

Area
{
    public Anchor anchor  { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Points> points { get; set; }
}
```

For this location `ID=10` in my database, the location is not null, position IS NOT NULL but area IS NULL.
That is why my query :

```
localhost/OData/Location(10)?$expand=position($expand=area($expand=points))
```

will generate that error. 
But it seems that there is a problem only when you expand a collection of a null object because if I expand Anchor object :

```
GET localhost/OData/Location(10)/?$expand=position($expand=area($expand=anchor))
```

then the location is expanded correctly and the expand stops at Area - so in json I get "area":null, no error, but expanding points collection crashes.

And the requirements from our front end team are to get the object fully expanded, so they will send a query with all sub-objects and sub-collections expanded. 
Anyone knows why `$expand` does not stop also for collections ?